# express response.render not work with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I want use ng-model to bind data sent from res.render("sub view path", data), but it doesn't work!

**controller**

```
$state.go("elements.editElement"
                        , {
                            "elementId": elementId,
                            "programId": newVal,
                            "elementTypeId": elementTypeId
                        }
```

**State provider**

```
.state('elements.editElement', {
                url: '/:elementTypeId/:elementId/:programId',                    
                views: {
                    'add@elements': {
                        templateUrl: 
                         'api/elements/editElement?elementTypeId=' + params.elementTypeId + '&elementId=' + params.elementId + '&programId=' + params.programId                              
                        ,controller: 'elementCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
```

**render code**

```
var elementType = {eType: "1", Name:"n1", Family:"f1"}
```

**render code**

```
router.get('/definations/addPerson', function (req, res) {    
    res.render('partials/sharedElements', elementType)
}
```

**jade**

```
div
  .row
    | Name
    input#Name(name="Name" type="text" ng-model="Name")
  .row
    | Family
    input#Family(name="Family" type="text" ng-model="Family")
  .row
    button(type="button" name="btnSave" ng-click="saveElement(#{eType})") Save
```

After rendering inputs are empty! However, when I set the value with `#{}` it works! for example : `value="#{Family}"` without ng-model. What's the problem here?

After render the html code is like this:

```
<div id="ddd" ui-view="add" class="col-lg-7 col-md-5 col-sm-7 ng-scope">
        <div class="ng-scope"><div class="row">Name
        <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" ng-model="Name" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"></div>
        <div class="row">Family <input id="Family" name="Family" type="text" ng-model="Family" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></div>
        <div class="row"><button type="button" name="btnSave" ng-click="saveElement(1)">Save</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additional information: I use angular-ui to call the route.

Comment: Can you post the rendered code before and after this change?

Comment: I've put before render(jade) and I edit question by adding after render now

Comment: you don't have any angular code here showing what `Family` represents in your client side JavaScript.  `ng-model="Family"` implies that you have a JavaScript variable `$scope.Family`, but you aren't showing that, you are showing some server side jade code.

Comment: @Claies but I pass it via elementType into render function and it works if I use `value="#{Family}"`. Should I correct something?

Comment: again, `#{Family}` is a node variable, `$scope.Family` (which `ng-model` is using) is an angular variable.  They aren't the same at all; one is on the server, the other is on the client.

Comment: I understood... I edited question by adding the controller and state provider. whole of my code is these. I have a button in jade as you can see. Now how should I get inputs value in controller at saveElement() function? I don't know what's the solution...(sorry I'm beginner with node and angular!)

Comment: that can't possibly be the entire controller file?  you don't have any reference to `$scope.Family` at all there.  Also, I'm only making a guess here but I think you misunderstand how `ng-model` works.  `ng-model` binds an input to a variable (`$scope.Family`), in this case, so that the value of the input is reflected in `$scope.Family`, and the value of `$scope.Family` is reflected in the input box.  it doesn't "set" the initial value of the input....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102212/discussion-between-siamak-ferdos-and-claies).